# Get $sum of grouped value Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have query like this:

```
{"$match": {$or: [{"to": system.mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}, {"from": system.mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}]}},
        {"$sort": {"createDate": -1}},
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$conversationId",
                "from": {"$first": "$from"},
                "to": {"$first": "$to"},
                "content": {"$first": "$content"},
                "createDate": {"$first": "$createDate"},
                "unreaded": {"$sum": {"$cond":
                                {if :
                                            {
                                                $and: [
                                                    {
                                                        "$eq": [
                                                            "$unreaded", 1
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "$eq": ["$to", system.mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }, then: 1, else: 0}}}
```

`unreaded` will return unreaded messages for each conversation, how can I get sum of all `unreaded` messages?

Comment: Please put down the document structure.

Comment: yes please . that would be very handy. please tell us how your document looks like.